# Texts between Two UILabels don't align

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have 4 UILabels aligning in a scroll view embeded in a view. I'am not using anto-layout. The 4 UILabels will display different strings. Sometimes only the first 2 or 3 labels show strings which is the way it works.

However, the text in the first UILabel always ident by 1 character. See the screenshot below. Horiaontally or vertically, texts in 4 aligned UILabels could not align and text in the first label always ident.

[image: UILabels display horizontally]
[image: UILabels display vertically]

In main storyboard, the 4 UILabels are set to the same height, width, X and Y. Other config settings are alignment to left, content-mode to top, baseline to none.

In my code, I only set text, font(name and size), text color for the UILabels.

I tried to set firstLineIdent to 0 for attributed String of the first label, but it does not work.

```
  NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
  CGFloat lengthForIndentation = 0.0;
  style.firstLineHeadIndent = lengthForIndentation;

  NSAttributedString *firstLine = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:[lines objectAtIndex:0] attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:style}];
  self.firstLineBottomVerseLabel.attributedText = firstLine;
```

I want to know, how to stop the text in the first label from auto indentation and align the texts between labels.

Thanks in advance.

> With the reminder of the comment below, I found my mistake in the plist where all strings start with space. I am so sorry to bother you all.

Comment: Are you sure it is the text and not the label itself?  You can check this by setting the backgroundColor of the labels.  I would also be helpful if you can show the Attributes and Size Inspectors of one of the labels that is giving you the trouble.

Comment: Have you tried logging your text? If you NSLog( @"<<%@>>", label1Text ) etc., are there definitely no spaces at the start of your text? Japanese and Chinese use different space characters than Roman languages, so I wouldn't be shocked to see whatever library is removing spaces around your data might not consider it a space.

Comment: @uliwitness Thank you so much. It was my mistake. All strings starts with a Chinese space.